# Library to clean up and simplify filenames?

Tags: java, string, hibernate, spring, apache-commons

I'd like to convert filenames that have spaces and symbols to contain only the characters A-Z, a-z, a period, a hyphen, and an underscore. Something like this regex: `([a-z][A-Z]-_\.)+`

Of course, I could just do this with a regex. But since I've already including many libraries in my project (Spring, Hibernate, Apache Commons, and much more), I was wondering if something like this is already available.

So a string like this:

```
This>is some(string,with $invalid*-chars).jpg
```

Would be converted to this:

```
This_is_some_string_with__invalid_-chars_.jpg
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No library is going to be able to offer you something simpler than `String.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]", "_")`

Comment: True. I just figured this would be a common enough requirement that some standard helper library would have a `StringUtil.cleanFilename(name)` type of method. No big deal. By the way, the correct regex to use is: `"somestring".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]", "_")`.

Comment: Would be good if the answer could be updated with the regex in the comment as it is better.

Comment: Worth noting that this will not work with any system where users might have files with non-alphanumeric characters (Chinese, any language with accents, etc)